# Complex solutions for Fermat-Catalan conjecture

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, open-problem

The [Fermat-Catalan conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fermat-CatalanConjecture.html) is that $a^m + b^n = c^k$ has only a finite number of solutions when $a, b, c$ are positive coprime integers, and $m,n,k$ are positive integers satisfying $\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{k} <1$. There are currently only 10 solutions known (listed at the end of this post). My question concerns the case where $a, b, c$ are positive coprime [Gaussian integers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianInteger.html). I've found two solutions. Is there a clever method for finding more? I've used brute force techniques.

- $(8+5i)^2+(5+3i)^3=(1+2i)^7$
- $(20+9i)^2+(1+8i)^3=(1+i)^{15}$
- $(1+2i)^7+(49+306i)^2=(27+37i)^3$ (Zander)
- $(44+83i)^2+(31+39i)^3=(5+2i)^7$ (Zander)
- $(238+72i)^3+(7+6i)^8=(7347−1240i)^2$ (Oleg567)

Here are the known solutions over integers.

- $1^m+2^3=3^2$
- $2^5+7^2=3^4$
- $13^2+7^3=2^9$
- $2^7+17^3=71^2$
- $3^5+11^4=122^2$
- $33^8+1549034^2=15613^3$
- $1414^3+2213459^2=65^7$
- $9262^3+15312283^2=113^7$
- $17^7+76271^3=21063928^2$
- $43^8+96222^3=30042907^2$

Comment: I take it you're the E Pegg who submitted those two to mathworld? That's sort of cool.

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Pegg,_Jr.) you?

Comment: Yes, it's me. I'm the same guy.

Comment: Hi Ed, I remember you from NKS SS 1.

Comment: I can't contribute a clever method, but I also found these by brutish force: $(1+2i)^7+(49+306i)^2=(27+37i)^3$ and $(44+83i)^2+(31+39i)^3=(5+2i)^7$.

Comment: Great solutions, Zander -- I added them to the short list.

Comment: Hi, how about $(1+i)^5 + 1^n = (1-2i)^2$. $n>3$. Of course, it is some mixed case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the next complex solution! :)
$$(238+72i)^3+(7+6i)^8=(7347−1240i)^2$$

(There is no new method here. Just small contribution to the problem.)

Comment: Added it to the list.  What were the bounds of your search?

Comment: The bounds of my search were:  $|\mathrm{Re}a|<B^{1/2}$, $|\mathrm{Im}a|<B^{1/2}$, $|\mathrm{Re}b|<B^{1/3}$, $|\mathrm{Im}b|<B^{1/3}$, $|\mathrm{Re}c|<B^{1/8}$, $|\mathrm{Im}c|<B^{1/8}$, where $B = 0\mathrm{x}80.00.00.00.00$ (hexadecimal) ~ $550\cdot 10^9$. Search form: $\pm a^2 \pm b^3 \pm c^8 =0$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small portion of what I have found:

$i^{4 m}+2^3=3^2$ where integer $m \ge 2$, i.e. the smallest is $i^8+2^3=3^2$

$(1+i)^2=i^{4 m+1}+i^{4 n+1}$ where integer $m \ge 1$, $n \ge 1$, i.e. the smallest is $(1+i)^2=i^5+i^5$

$(78-78 i)^2=(23 i)^3+i^{4 m+3}$ where integer $m \ge 1$, i.e. the smallest is $(78-78 i)^2=(23 i)^3+i^7$

$(11+11 i)^2+i^{4 m+1}=(3 i)^5$ where integer $m \ge 1$, i.e. the smallest is $(11+11 i)^2+i^5=(3 i)^5$

$(34-34 i)^2=(5 i)^3+(3 i)^7$

$(36+19 i)^2+(9-8 i)^3=(1+i)^{13}$

Comment: +1 for last solution $(1+i)^{13}$ !  2 examples more with $(ai)^n$:    $$(3i)^{13} + (2761-2761i)^2 = (239i)^3,$$ $$(2797i)^3 + (13i)^9 = (75090-75090i)^2.$$